# GAS performance slower than other server-side JavaScript

Tags: google-apps-script

Working on a `Google Sites` site, which takes data from a spreadsheet and builds several charts dynamically, I mentioned that Google Apps Script works quite slow. I profiled the code and optimized it, by using the [Cache](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_cache) Service, where it is possible. After optimization the charting code takes approx. 3 secs (2759 ms is one of the fastest times, which I have ever seen) to draw 11 charts having 127 rows. And this time is for the case when all data are placed to the cache. The 1st execution time, which fetches data from the spreadsheet and places them to the cache, is around of 10 sec. The profiled code required sufficient time (tens of milliseconds) in simple places. To measure the GAS performance, I wrote a very simple procedure and executed it in the GAS environment, as deployed web application, and in the [Caja Playground](http://caja.appspot.com/). Also I submitted an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1678) to the GAS issue tracker.

[Eric Koleda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/702875/eric-koleda) reasonably [mentioned](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1678#c1), that it is not correct to compare a server code with a code running on a client. I rewrote the benchmark code and here are the results. The details and explanations are the following.

```
Engine          |List To Map|Adjust|Quick Sort|Sort|Complete|
GAS             |        138|   196|       155|  38|     570|
rhino-1.6.5     |         67|    44|        31|   9|     346|
spidermonkey-1.7|         40|    36|        11|   5|     104|
```

- `GAS` - a row containing the execution times of different functions ran on the GAS engine. All the times are in milliseconds. The GAS execution time drifts in quite wide limits. In the table are the most fast times which I had across 5-10 executions. The worst `Complete` time, which I have seen, was 1194 ms. The source code is [here](https://script.google.com/a/bastra.com/d/1j9K0wFh_nnqNGb03do0o_MVKXhh0wFPTG-4hSWMcW9ZRgsstTT-Ft4_m/edit). The results are [here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzbQ9NRRX8W-E5B9Jb2K4OAeNdm4v0FSzifSXsXdpxXru_U3fE/exec).
- `rhino-1.6.5` and `spidermonkey-1.7` - rows contain the execution times of the same functions as `GAS` but executed on correspondent Javascript engines using [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/). The code and times for these engines are [here](http://ideone.com/dbXpa) and [here](http://ideone.com/RnFDU).

The benchmark code contains a few functions.

- `List To Map [listToMap]` - a function which converts a list of objects to a map having a compound key. It is taken from the site script and takes approx. 9.2% (256 of 2759 ms) of the charting code.
- `Adjust [adjustData_]` - a function which converts all date columns in a matrix to a text in a predefined format, transposes it and converts rows from the `[[[a], [1]], [[b], [2]]]` form to the `[[a, 1], [b, 2]]` one. It is also taken from the script and consumes approx. 30.7% (857 of 2759 ms).
- `Sort` - a standard `Array.sort` function, it is included to the test to see how fast work standard functions.
- `Quick Sort [quick_sort]` - a quick sort function taken [here](http://en.literateprograms.org/Quicksort_%28JavaScript%29). It is added to the benchmark to compare with the `Array.sort` function execution time.
- `Complete [test]` - a function which includes calls of functions, preparing test data, and the functions mentioned above. This time is not summary of times in a raw.

**Conclusion:** The GAS functions execution time drifts. The GAS `Complete` function works **1.6** times slower than the slowest competitor. The GAS standard `Array.sort` function is **4** times slower than the slowest of two other engines. The service `List To Map` and `Adjust` in summary are **3** times slower (334 ms vs 111 ms) than slowest competitor. The functions take 39.2% (1113 of 2759 ms) of the charting function. I did not expect that these functions work so slow. It is possible to optimize them, for instance, using the cache. Let's assume that after optimization, these functions execution time will be 0 ms. In this case the charting function execution is 1646 ms.

**Wishes:** If GAS Team could optimize their engine to the speed of the slowest competitor, it is possible to expect that the execution time reduces till 1 sec or less. Also it would be great to optimize time to fetch data from a spreadsheet. I understand that the spreadsheets are not designed to handle a big amount of data, but in any case, it will increase overall performance.

Comment: did you run your tets multiple times ? are results contant ? From my experience execution time is highly variable depending on uncontrolable  and probably multiple parameters

Comment: @Sergeinsas, for sure, I executed both scripts multiple times. The GAS execution time is 8 secs and more. The Caja script execution time is around 5 ms.

Comment: @Sergeinsas. [Here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbypGjQbzQDU4qjGsN7tk6wsF3uOmloS1MiDhME-ds2NGqOc3zDM/exec) is the deployed GAS script and [its source code](https://script.google.com/d/1WfXGEkU3IHq86dJyXi0QTId4-RPLjzgk7OEin12bh8atpRr78LmqpI6z/edit).

Comment: thanks, but I had deployed it already... I read values between 8 and sometimes up to 15 seconds ;-). What makes me happy thought is that is seems to be linear... reducing the loop to 500000 takes half the time. I'm curious about what Google team members will say/explain if they do.

Comment: @Sergeinsas, let's wait for an answer of the GAS support team, if they do. :)

Comment: @Serge Unbelievably slow indeed! And I have always blamed the API calls. How come we have never thought to test pure javascript like this Serge?

Comment: I submitted an issue to the tracker. See the Edit 00.

Comment: I got 41 secs once :-(, but mainly 8-15 secs.

Comment: I starred your issue. Nice test. I think there's warm up time to load the script into an instance (I'm assuming a java vm with rhino). That's just a guess of course because I've never seen any documentation about the environment nor discussed it with anyone. In App Engine land you can keep an instance warm/running as long as you pay for it or have quota.

Comment: For me it ran in between 8 and 15 seconds (across 5 or so invocations). Further, I rewrote the ui bit to use ContentService instead of uiApp (simply return ContentService.createTextOutput('time: ' + res.diff + 'ms') to exclude any impact of uiApp. The results didn't change (9 to 19 seconds across 5 invocations).

Comment: @PeterHerrmann. I don't think 8 secs are spent to load, warm up or compile the script. I wrapped the `calc` function call with a loop with 10 iterations. The result is the same approx. 8 secs for one iteration.

Comment: @megabyte1024 I agree that "your time" is ~0 and "gas service time" (GST) is ~8 secs. Part of the GST would surely be loading the instance but yes, not all. It is all google's time though and not your code's :) It would be very helpful to know.

Comment: @PeterHerrmann. In my test the time required for load Google services, to instance my code, etc. is not taken into an account. The code between two Dates is already instances. If to delete the 'for' operator from the `calc` function, the `diff` will be 0. i.e. 8 secs is pure execution time of the `calc` function and not time to instance my code plus execution time.

Comment: @megabyte1024 Aha, ok, got it. I had completely misunderstood.

Comment: Interesting edit!  Thanks. A lot of work I guess :-)

Comment: @Sergeinsas. Indeed, but it was very interesting.

Comment: Hey ! Congratulations, you're number one today...not bad for an unsung hero :-)

Comment: @Sergeinsas, Bo.. Just mentioned... but I am far away from you, Henrique and other contributors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to replicate this performance, and I'll post updates on the issue as I receive them.

Comment: Eric, thank you very much. I already read the issue tracker answer. I agree that it is not correct to compare Caja (client) and server scripts. I ported my original "benchmark" script to run it on a [ideone.com](http://ideone.com) server. The results are [276 ms](http://ideone.com/L9Ejj) for the `spidermonkey-1.7` engine and [90 ms](http://ideone.com/AE96R) for the `rhino-1.6.5` engine. I also create more real examples - quick sort. The results are [spidermonkey](http://ideone.com/YHYq0), [rhino](http://ideone.com/uCnjX), [GAS](http://goo.gl/I12sg)([code](http://goo.gl/Aa43e)). Continue...

Comment: Great research, and much better comparisons. It looks like Apps Script is a bit more comparable in those quick sort tests, but still not great.

Comment: Now I work on optimizing my script, to get rid of very obvious bottlenecks and to discuss the performance not theoretically but using a real script.

Comment: I updated my original post. Now, I think, it is closer to reality.