# Can I change my code so that my script runs faster?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to find out two things.

1. Can I optimize my code so that it will run faster
2. Is there a way to test the speed of my script.

My script is simply pulling data from a URL (Example: https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/items?q=Water&max=100&format=json) that will be pasted into the first cell of a spreadsheet. It then populates the cells with the first column storing the title and the second column storing the summary.

I'm using a trigger that will execute the script onEdit() so that it will run whenever a edit is made to the first cell of the spreadsheet.

Any pointers, tips, or even a go look here is appreciated

Here's my code,

```
function respondToSearch() {

     // Gets the active sheet in a spreadsheet
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 

     // Gets sheet 1 and sets the first column to a width of 200 and the second 
     column to width 500
     var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0].setColumnWidth(1, 200).setColumnWidth(2, 500);
     var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

     // Gets the value from the top left cell in a range
     var dataRange = activeSheet.getDataRange().getValue();

     // Sends an HTTP request to fetch the URL
     var searchResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(dataRange);

     // Get the response as a string and parse (string is in JSON format) 
     var parsedResponse = Utilities.jsonParse(searchResponse.getContentText());

     // Array to hold letter corresponding to spreadsheet columns
     var cellLetters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", 
     "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t"];

     // Loop through the "item" objects and display the properties in the 
     spreadsheet
     for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {  
       for (var j = 0; j < parsedResponse.items.length; j++) {      

       // Starts with items[0] (1st object) and displays the properties
       var parsedItems = [parsedResponse.items[j].title, parsedResponse.items[j]
       .summary];

       // If a property is not undefined print the property in the spreadsheet 
       else print "N/A"
       if (parsedItems[i] != undefined) {
         var print = parsedItems[i];
       }
       else {
         var print = "N/A";
       }

       // Stores the current letter corresponding to the current spreadsheet column
       var cellLtr = cellLetters[i];

       // Starts the row available to display data at number 2
       var cellNum = [j + 2];
       var cell = cellLtr + cellNum;

       sheet.setActiveCell(cell).setFontSize("9").setHorizontalAlignment("left")
       .setVerticalAlignment("top").setValue(print);
      }
     }
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I optimize my code so that it will run faster

I think it is possible. Try to rewrite your code to set the font size and the alignments not for every cells but for the whole range.

> Is there a way to test the speed of my script.

Yes. The code should looks line the following

```
var start = new Date();
my_time_consuming_function();
var diff = new Date() - start;
Logger.log("my_time_consuming_function takes: " + diff + " ms");
```

Comment: May be silly questions but, should I put the code (speed test) at the beginning or end of my other code?? my_time_consuming_function() is not defined? Should I put start and diff in that function??

Comment: Think I figured it out, I put var start at the beginning and var diff at the end with log. I didn't use the my-time function part. Does that sound right??

Comment: @jc72. My code is only an example and not a complete solution. Instead of the `my_time_consuming_function()` function call you have to insert a function call for which you need to measure the execution time, i.e. `respondToSearch`.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid looking up and creating `parsedItems[i]` and changing `cellLtr` in every iteration of `j`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var cellLtr = cellLetters[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < parsedResponse.items.length; j++) {
        var print = (i == 0 ? parsedResponse.items[j].title : parsedResponse.items[j].summary);
        if (print == undefined)
            print = "N/A";

        var cell = cellLtr + (j + 2);

        sheet.setActiveCell(cell).setFontSize("9").setHorizontalAlignment("left")
            .setVerticalAlignment("top").setValue(print);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure the the JSPerf can help to estimate performance of a Google Aps Script, because the JSPerf measures the performance of a Web Browser Javascript engine and the Google Apps scripts are running on the Google servers. Have you tried to start JSPerf from a Google Apps Script?

Comment: @megabyte1024 You're right. I edited my answer. I initially meant he could use it to find bottlenecks not caused by calls to the apps API. But it wouldn't be reliable, because Google servers can (and probably do) have optimizations that browsers don't, so I guess I just wrote it without thinking.

Comment: Unfortunately GAS is no very efficient now. See my [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854575/gas-is-slow-am-i-wrong) about it.