# How to induce a spreadsheet's onFormSubmit trigger in script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to trigger a spreadsheet’s onFormSubmit  in script? That is, instead of using a google form to trigger onFormSubmit?
I attempted the below sendHttpPost code posting to a spreadsheet Web App:

```
function sendHttpPostSelf() {
var payload = {
      "name" : "name",
      "comment" : "comment",
    };
  var options = {
      "method" : "post",
      "payload" : payload
    };
var url="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzlVoiDQMbLe4yliErDoNub6A0m3tijSfPAUMEBENgIikQnLQ_H/exec";
var resp=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
Logger.log(resp.getContentText());
}
```

The code correctly triggers doPost() in the spreadsheet Web App. But, the code does not trigger the spreadsheet’s onFormSubmit. Alternately, is there any way to script an *onInsert* trigger when inserting into a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list of things-that-don't-trigger-onEdit, along with their issue tracking ids, were provided in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15234631/1677912). There is example code there that demonstrates detection of a new row... but the caveat is that you need to do some other type of edit to trigger it!

So, bad news - despite Arun's answer, neither inserting rows nor a script writing values will trigger onEdit.

Comment: Thank You Mogsdad, I appreciate the corrected answer, it saved me some painful debugging!

Answer (score 0):

onFormSubmit trigger will only fire when a Google Form submits. It's pretty tricky/unsupported to get an Apps Script code to trigger that.

If you just want the ability to detect new rows, you can use the onEdit trigger to and check the range to see what got inserted.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events

Comment: Thanks for input Arun, will onEdit trigger work when a new row is inserted with script? regards Commet

Comment: Yes, in fact it will work in all scenarios and you'll have to figure out if in fact this was a row insert. Play around with it and you might see some interesting options with it.

Comment: Arun, please see the corrected answer above; I confirmed that onEdit trigger does not fire on inserts also. I will submit a New Feature request in Issue Tracker for a working onInsert trigger.

Comment: ..I added another comment to vote for a new onInsert trigger to a New Feature request already there: Issue 1363

Answer (score 0):

please tell me if I'm wrong but of what I understood, you want to submit values not passing through a google form, but with a form you builded yourself and you want to submit with a doPost action.
If so, here is what you can do:
1/ insert the data from the doPost in your spreadsheet with a appenrow()
2/ call the function that is usually called with onFormSubmit inside the doPost() (you need to transfert to the onFormSubmit function the good arguments (as if it was called with a real formSubmit)

here is a sample function:

```
function onformSubmit(e){ 
  var answers = e.values;
  if (typeof(answers) == "undefined") answers = e;
  MailApp.sendEmail("youremailadress", "form first answer", answers[1]);

}
function doPost(e){
  MailApp.sendEmail("youremailadress","reponse doPost",e.parameter.name);
  SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheet id").getSheetByName("spreadsheet name").appendRow([new Date(),e.parameter.name,e.parameter.comment]);
  var toe = [new Date(),e.parameter.name,e.parameter.comment];
  onformSubmit(toe);
  return(ContentService.createTextOutput().setContent("okey"));
}
function submitIt(){
  var payload = {
      "name" : "name",
      "comment" : "comment",
    };
  var options = {
      "method" : "post",
      "payload" : payload
    };
var url="https://script.google.com/macros/s/yourscripturl/exec";
var resp=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
}
```

When you launch submitIt() it will call the doPost that will write the row in your spreadsheet just like when the form is submited and then it will call the function onformsubmit (that is normally called when the form is submited)

Comment: The code does not trigger the spreadsheet’s onFormSubmit - onFormSubmit trigger will only fire when a Google Form submits...Please add a comment to implement as a New Request in Issue Tracker #1363 if you like.

Comment: @user1387318 indeed, it won't trigger the (onFormSubmit trigger) but it will do "as if" it was triggering the onFormSubmit trigger: the doPost will add the data to the spreadsheet and then call the function onFormSubmit() <-- that's the function triggered with onFormSubmit trigger - sorry I thought you where looking for an alternate solution to the onFormSubmit trigger