# Execute GAS on sheet movement in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to execute a GAS (custom function in Google Spreadsheet) when a sheet is moved (drag & drop)?

I wrote this script on Web Applications, [How do I Sum Throughout Different Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/42960/29140), but the re-calculation of the script is rather slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no trigger for re-arranging the tabs of a spreadsheet. The closest you can get is an installable onEdit trigger, however there are many types of changes (aka edits) that are excluded by the trigger.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232405/detect-user-inserting-row-or-column-in-a-google-spreadsheet-and-reacting-in-a-sc/15234631#15234631) for more about onEdit triggers and what they don't react to.

Comment: FYI: I revised my answer in order to solve my problem. Now the script has to be triggered via a menu option.