# Google Script not triggered following external REST api update

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a Google sheet that has an onEdit triggered function that works fine if I edit the doc myself.

But when the sheet is updated via the sheet API from an external app the event does't occur. Can you help me find a method to generate this update event following a write to the sheet from an external source,
thx

Answer (score 1):

Some limitations of `onEdit()` are described in [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232405/detect-user-inserting-row-or-column-in-a-google-spreadsheet-and-reacting-in-a-sc/15234631#15234631).

If you install that function to trigger "on change", you should catch the event. Note that the event that's delivered in this case is not as rich as an edit trigger receives. See [Understanding Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events).