# Inserting static time on sheets app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to insert the current time as a static value in Google sheets on a mobile device.

The keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> works on the desktop but not the mobile app and `"=NOW()"` works to insert the time but as a dynamic value.

Is there a script I can use to cut and paste the dynamic value as a static value?

Answer (score 4):

On a mobile app, none of the script-based UI extensions will be visible, but if you're willing to use the full web interface on your device (ouch), you could add a menu or sidebar add-on that inserts the current time into the active cell.

Here's a hack that watches for specific text being added to a cell, then updates the content with the current date. (You can format the cell to display time instead.) Just put `#datetime` in any cell, and watch it be replaced. Note though, that this only works for EDITs, not [other types of changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232405/detect-user-inserting-row-or-column-in-a-google-spreadsheet-and-reacting-in-a-sc/15234631#15234631). Tested with Sheets app on iOS7.2, and it works.

```
/**
 * onEdit trigger function is called whenever text is edited in
 * the spreadsheet.
 *
 * If the content criteria is met, content will be replaced with
 * current time.
 */
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.value.toUpperCase() == '#DATETIME') {
    e.range.setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

As of today, Google Sheets App has an icon for inserting static DateTime.

You have to select the entire column or cell format as `Date Time` from the `Format` menu first.

`Format > Number > Date time`

[image]

Comment: This is great, but it doesn't insert the current date and time, I have to select it.  This is a couple of taps because it defaults to the current date and time, but the time is not accurate to the second (it doesn't even insert a second!) and tapping delays a second or two as well.

Comment: I do not see the calendar icon in the iOS version of the app