# Paste values from one sheet to another and remove duplicates

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two worksheets in my google spreadsheet:

Input data is coming into the `Get Data` worksheet via the `importxml` function.

However, I would like to copy all values of the `Get Data` sheet to the `Final Data` sheet and if there are duplicates(in terms of rows) append the unique row.

Here is what I tried:

```
function onEdit() {
   //get the data from old Spreadsheet
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1bm2ia--F2b0495iTJotp4Kv1QAW-wGUGDUROwM9B-D0");
 var dataRange = ss.getSheetByName("Get Data").getRange(1, 1, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn());
 var dataRangeFinalData = ss.getSheetByName("Final Data").getRange(1, 1, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn());
 var myData = dataRange.getValues();
 //Open new Spreadsheet & paste the data
newSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1bm2ia--F2b0495iTJotp4Kv1QAW-wGUGDUROwM9B-D0");
Logger.log(newSS.getLastRow());

newSS.getSheetByName("Final Data").getRange(newSS.getLastRow()+1, 1, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn()).setValues(myData);
//remove duplicates in the new sheet
removeDups(dataRangeFinalData)
}

function getId() {
  Browser.msgBox('Spreadsheet key: ' + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId());
}

function removeDups(array) {
  var outArray = [];
  array.sort(lowerCase);
  function lowerCase(a,b){
    return a.toLowerCase()>b.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;// sort function that does not "see" letter case
  }
  outArray.push(array[0]);
  for(var n in array){
    Logger.log(outArray[outArray.length-1]+'  =  '+array[n]+' ?');
    if(outArray[outArray.length-1].toLowerCase()!=array[n].toLowerCase()){
      outArray.push(array[n]);
    }
  }
  return outArray;
}
```

Below you can find the link to a sample spreadsheet:

[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bm2ia--F2b0495iTJotp4Kv1QAW-wGUGDUROwM9B-D0/edit?usp=sharing)

My problem is that the data does not get pasted.

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: In the sample you posted the data gets pasted to row 23.

Comment: @RobinGertenbach Yes, true! That is also basically my problem. How to post the data to the other sheet?

Comment: Not sure I'm following you. At the moment you are defining the same Spreadsheet for source and target and paste the data from Get Data to Final Data in the range you are specifying so the data is being pasted?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach Thx for your reply! I would appreciate if you could provide an example as I am quite new to google script! Thx in advance!

Comment: I'm just looking at what your script is doing at the moment. you are assigning the same spreadsheet to both `ss` and `newSS`. Then you get the data from sheet and save it in my data and write that to the Final Data sheet after the last filled row of the first sheet in your spreadsheet (`ss.getlastRow()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** See script at bottom.

An `onEdit()` function is inappropriate for your use case, as cell contents modified by spreadsheet functions are not considered "edit" events. You can read more about that [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15234631/1677912). If you want this to be automated, then a timed trigger function would be appropriate. Alternatively, you could manually invoke the function by a menu item, say. I'll leave that to you to decide, as the real meat of your problem is how to ensure row-level uniqueness in your final data set.

### Merging unique rows

Although your original code is incomplete, it appears you were intending to first remove duplicates from the source data, utilizing case-insensitive string comparisons. I'll suggest instead that some other JavaScript magic would help here.

We're interested in uniqueness in our destination data, so we need to have a way to compare new rows to what we already have. If we had arrays of strings or numbers, then we could just use the techniques in [How to merge two arrays in Javascript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items). However, there's a complication here, because we have an array of arrays, and arrays cannot be directly compared.

#### Hash

Fine - we could still compare rows element-by-element, which would require a simple loop over all columns in the rows we were comparing. Simple, but slow, what we would call an [O(n<sup>2</sup>) solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)  (Order n-squared). As the number of rows to compare increased, the number of unique comparison operations would increase exponentially. So, let's not do that.

Instead, we'll create a separate data structure that mirrors our destination data but is very efficient for comparisons, a [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

In JavaScript we can quickly access the properties of an object by their name, or key. Further, that key can be any string. We can create a simple hash table then, with an object whose properties are named using strings generated from the rows of our destination data. For example, this would create a hash object, then add the array `row` to it:

```js
var destHash = {};
destHash[row.join('')] = true; // could be anything
```

To create our key, we're `join`ing all the values in the `row` array with no separator. Now, to test for uniqueness of a row, we just check for existence of an object property with an identically-formed key. Like this:

```js
var alreadyExists = destHash.hasOwnProperty(row.join(''));
```

One additional consideration: since the source data can conceivably contain duplicate rows that aren't yet in the destination data, we need to continuously expand the hash table as unique rows are identified.

#### Filter & Concatenate

JavaScript provides two built-in array methods that we'll use to [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out known rows, and [concatenate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) only unique rows to our destination data.

In its simple form, that would look like this:

```js
// Concatentate source rows to dest rows if they satisfy a uniqueness filter
var mergedData = destData.concat(sourceData.filter(function (row) {
  // Return true if given row is unique
}));
```

You can read that as "create an array named `mergedData` that consists of the current contents of the array named `destData`, with filtered rows of the `sourceData` array concatenated to it."

You'll find in the final function that it's a little more complex due to the other considerations already mentioned.

### Update spreadsheet

Once we have our `mergedData` array, it just needs to be written into the destination Sheet.

**Padding rows:** The source data contains rows of inconsistent width, which will be a problem when calling `setValues()`, which expects all rows to be squared off. This will require that we examine and pad rows to avoid this sort of error:

> Incorrect range width, was 6 but should be 5 (line ?, file "Code")

Padding rows is done by `push`ing blank "cells" at the end of the row array until it reaches the intended length.

```js
for (var col=mergedData[row].length; col<mergedWidth; col++)
  mergedData[row].push('');
```

With that taken care of for each row, we're finally ready to write out the result.

### Final script

```js
function appendUniqueRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Get Data');
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Final Data');

  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var destData = destSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Check whether destination sheet is empty
  if (destData.length === 1 && "" === destData[0].join('')) {
    // Empty, so ignore the phantom row
    destData = [];
  }

  // Generate hash for comparisons
  var destHash = {};
  destData.forEach(function(row) {
    destHash[row.join('')] = true; // could be anything
  });

  // Concatentate source rows to dest rows if they satisfy a uniqueness filter
  var mergedData = destData.concat(sourceData.filter(function (row) {
    var hashedRow = row.join('');
    if (!destHash.hasOwnProperty(hashedRow)) {
      // This row is unique
      destHash[hashedRow] = true;   // Add to hash for future comparisons
      return true;                  // filter -> true
    }
    return false;                   // not unique, filter -> false
  }));

  // Check whether two data sets were the same width
  var sourceWidth = (sourceData.length > 0) ? sourceData[0].length : 0;
  var destWidth = (destData.length > 0) ? destData[0].length : 0;
  if (sourceWidth !== destWidth) {
    // Pad out all columns for the new row
    var mergedWidth = Math.max(sourceWidth,destWidth);
    for (var row=0; row<mergedData.length; row++) {
      for (var col=mergedData[row].length; col<mergedWidth; col++)
        mergedData[row].push('');
    }
  }

  // Write merged data to destination sheet
  destSheet.getRange(1, 1, mergedData.length, mergedData[0].length)
           .setValues(mergedData);
}
```