# How can I detect new row or updated row in Google Sheets through the api?

Tags: google-sheets-api

Can anyone help me figure out how to detect new row or updated row in a Google sheets through the api ? Something like a webhook ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can only do it with the help of Apps Script. You can use a trigger here to detect if something is change in your spreadsheet. The [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) let Apps Script run a function automatically when a certain event, like opening a document, occurs. Simple triggers are a set of reserved functions built into Apps Script, like the function onOpen(e), which executes when a user opens a Google Docs, Sheets, or Forms file. For more information, check this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232405).

Comment: Very interesting. I've never used Apps script yet. Is there a way to get a push notification or something similar through an Apps script function to use it outside of Google ?

Comment: is there any way to know one row is completely edited ? onedit or onchange not working.