# Google Spreadsheet ranking values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im currently setting up a decision matrix with Google Spreadsheet and I want to implement a ranking feature for the results. I wouldnt do this, if there were only 4 options, but in my case there are like 32 options available...

I tried to do this with the google script api, but the result is kinda disappointing:

```
function Ranking() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
var alldata = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var data = [];
var j = 8;
for (var i = 0; i <= 31; i++) {
data [i] = alldata[18][j];
j= j+2;
}
var sorted = data.slice().sort(function(a,b){return b-a});
var ranks = data.slice().map(function(v){return sorted.indexOf(v)+1});
sheet.getRange("I20").setValue(ranks[0]);
sheet.getRange("K20").setValue(ranks[1]);
sheet.getRange("M20").setValue(ranks[2]);
sheet.getRange("O20").setValue(ranks[3]);
sheet.getRange("Q20").setValue(ranks[4]);
sheet.getRange("S20").setValue(ranks[5]);
sheet.getRange("U20").setValue(ranks[6]);
sheet.getRange("W20").setValue(ranks[7]);
sheet.getRange("Y20").setValue(ranks[8]);
sheet.getRange("AA20").setValue(ranks[9]);
sheet.getRange("AC20").setValue(ranks[10]);
sheet.getRange("AE20").setValue(ranks[11]);
sheet.getRange("AG20").setValue(ranks[12]);
sheet.getRange("AI20").setValue(ranks[13]);
sheet.getRange("AK20").setValue(ranks[14]);
sheet.getRange("AM20").setValue(ranks[15]);
sheet.getRange("AO20").setValue(ranks[16]);
sheet.getRange("AQ20").setValue(ranks[17]);
sheet.getRange("AS20").setValue(ranks[18]);
sheet.getRange("AU20").setValue(ranks[19]);
sheet.getRange("AW20").setValue(ranks[20]);
sheet.getRange("AY20").setValue(ranks[21]);
sheet.getRange("BA20").setValue(ranks[22]);
sheet.getRange("BC20").setValue(ranks[23]);
sheet.getRange("BE20").setValue(ranks[24]);
sheet.getRange("BG20").setValue(ranks[25]);
sheet.getRange("BI20").setValue(ranks[26]);
sheet.getRange("BK20").setValue(ranks[27]);
sheet.getRange("BM20").setValue(ranks[28]);
sheet.getRange("BO20").setValue(ranks[29]);
sheet.getRange("BQ20").setValue(ranks[30]);
sheet.getRange("BR20").setValue(ranks[31]);
}
```

As you can see, the code is really sloppy. Thats probably because I have never done javascript before and my coding knowledge is very basic in general.

Is there a way to implement such a feature directly in the spreadsheet, without the need of the script api?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<numRanks;i++)
    sheet.getRange(20, i*2+9).setValue(ranks[i]);
```

Basically you just iterate a for loop over the twentieth row every other column.

Function documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange%28Integer,Integer%29).

Answer (score 0):

Jason's answer is clear & short - but it's not efficient because of the number of calls to the Spreadsheet Service.

For background about this concern, see [Google Apps Script Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices). You may also want to look at [What is faster: ScriptDb or SpreadsheetApp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145918/what-is-faster-scriptdb-or-spreadsheetapp).

You've already got an Array of `ranks`; if you transpose that into a two-dimensional array with the values in rows, then you can write it all out in one `setValues()` operation.

```
sheet.getRange("I20:BR20").setValues(transpose([ranks]));
```

Here's a transpose function, from [Google Spreadsheet Script - How to Transpose / Rotate Multi-dimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621470/google-spreadsheet-script-how-to-transpose-rotate-multi-dimensional-array).

```
function transpose(a)
{
  return Object.keys(a[0]).map(function (c) { return a.map(function (r) { return r[c]; }); });
}
```

There is still iteration happening, but it's in the transpose function now, instead of around the `setValue()` call, so this will run much quicker.