# TypeError: Cannot read property 'xx' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, stripe-payments

I was trying to call Stripe API for some payment information. The code is as follow:

```
function callStripe() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXX");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("XXX");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var startRow = 1; // First row of data to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < lastRow + 1; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var missedFee = row[6];

    if (missedFee == "") {  //only call for missing figures
       var txId = sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 2).getDisplayValue();
       var url = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/balance_transactions/" + txId;

       var params = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {Authorization: "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("XXX:")}
        };
       var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
       var transaction = JSON.parse(res);


         var fee = transaction["fee"];
         var net = transaction["net"];
         sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 7).setValue(fee / 100);
         sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 9).setValue(net / 100);}
  }}
```

I can get what I need from the API after running the function, but there is an error as below:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '6' of undefined (line 112, file "Code")
```

Line 112 is referring to

```
var missedFee = row[6];
```

May I know what has done wrong?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/43829052/1595451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You defined your loop `for (var i = 0; i < lastRow + 1; ++i)`

Given that you start with `0` (which is correct since the first array entry is `0`), your last `i` should be `lastRow-1`

**Sample:**

- Lets say you have three rows, then you want to iterate three times
- Your rows will be `data[0]`, `data[1]` and `data[2]`
- Now, if you define `i < lastRow + 1` as the condition to execute the loop, it will also execute for `i = 3`
- But there is no `data[3]` (that would be the forth row) and thus, there is no column 7 in row 4 (`var missedFee = row[6];`)
- This is what gives you the error