# Google Form to pull data from spreadsheet and email to user

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a spreadsheet containing all of the annual leave balances for each staff member. I have a form that the staff will fill out, and I would like it to pull the their data from the spreadsheet and send them an email with the result.

I am having trouble with the matching of form data to the spreadsheet data, and extracting the related cells. Here is the code:

```
function SendGoogleForm(e) {  
  try {      

    var subject = "Leave Balance Request";  
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("url").getSheetByName("Check Leave");

    var email = e.namedValues["BCA National email address"];
    var sheet =  SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("url").getSheetByName("Leave Summary");
    var cell = sheet.getRange("F3:F3");
    var getcell = cell.getCell(1,1);
    var pdate = getcell.setValue(e.namedValues['END date of leave requested']);
    var annualvalue = sheet.getRange("H6:H").getValues();
    var emaildata = sheet.getRange("A6:A").getValues();
    var username = e.namedValues["Username"];

    var message = "Your" + " " + e.namedValues["Type of leave requested"] + " " + "balance        is below" + "\n\n";   

    if (username == emaildata)  { message += "Annual Leave" + " : " +    annualvalue               + "\n\n"; }

    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);

  } 

  catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }
}
```

I tried this: [How do I search for and find the coordinates of a row in Google Spreadsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196655/how-do-i-search-for-and-find-the-coordinates-of-a-row-in-google-spreadsheets?rq=1)

But couldn't get it to work...

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When you write `var emaildata = sheet.getRange("A6:A").getValues();`, you are getting an array of arrays with strings. You will need to iterate in a `for loop` to test each value.

Something like that should work :

```
var message = "Your" + " " + e.namedValues["Type of leave requested"] + " " + "balance        is below" + "\n\n";   
for(var n in emaildata){
  if (username == emaildata[n][0])  { message += "Annual Leave" + " : " +    annualvalue               + "\n\n"; }
}
MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
```

}

Comment: Hmm I got this in the log:

[14-08-11 09:29:37:152 EST] Sheet.getRange([A6:A]) [0.031 seconds]
[14-08-11 09:29:37:276 EST] Range.getValues() [0.123 seconds]
[14-08-11 09:29:37:483 EST] MailApp.sendEmail([daniel@bcanational.com, Leave Balance Request, Your Personal Leave balance        is below

Annual Leave : 140.5904109589041,106.1204109589041,185.98041095890412,33.1304109589.... it goes on...

I would like to pinpoint the row that the matching name is in, then provide the balance of leave... 

I'm stumped!