# Editing checkbox choices in an existing Google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to create a survey using Google forms and spreadsheet that has dynamic checkbox answers, such that if participant 1 fills out an answer in the 'other' text box, then that answer is then available as a checkbox for subsequent responders.

I am using the following code:

```
//a function to update Question 2's answer options
function updateChoices() {

    //open the existing survey form  
    var form = FormApp.openById('1DEcjGr6x9KrlxapgIkFxreW1F-2Vlj_yDDzLQUhcmgk');

    //retrieve existing Question 2
    var items = form.getItems();
    var question2 = items[1];

    //retrieve previously submitted responses from response spreadsheet
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[1]);
    var numRows = ss.getLastRow()-1;
    var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,16,numRows,16).getValues();

    //declare a 1D array for existing survey answers
    var answersSoFar = new Array(numRows);

    //Pass the 2D array into the 1D array.
    for (i=0; i < numRows; i++){
    answersSoFar[i] = values[i][0];     
    }

    //update the choices for the question
    question2.setChoiceValues(answersSoFar);

}
```

I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot find function setChoiceValues in object Item. (line 57, file "Code")
```

even though the `setChoiceValues` method is in listed in the class item (line 57 is the last line of code).

I have also tried setting the choices individually using `setChoices` and `createChoice` in a for loop.

Answer (score 3):

Class Item is a generic object that needs to be cast as a specific Item Type before item-specific methods can be invoked. See the [preamble in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item) for Class Item. You could simply do this:

```
question2.asCheckboxItem().setChoiceValues(answersSoFar);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Spoiler alert: you've got some other issues in your function. If you want to be left alone to figure them out, stop reading now!

There's no need to call `SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet()`, as it has no benefit for this particular script.

Using `ss.getSheets()[1]` to get a handle on a specific sheet is unreliable, as the index is dependent on the ordering of sheets, which can change. If you need a specific sheet, it's better to refer to it by name. (Or by ID if you're using a method that takes a `gridId` parameter.)

What is the purpose of the values `16` in `getRange(2,16,numRows,16).getValues();`? That says the range starts at `P2` and extends `numRows` down and `16` columns to the right. Otherwise, you appear to be intending to generate a list of all the previous responses to question 2, which *should* be in column 3, or `C` (allowing for a timestamp and question 1 in `A..B`).

This line, `var answersSoFar = new Array(numRows);`, creates an array with a single element in it, a Number, which is equal to the number of rows in the sheet. It *does not* create an array with `numRows` elements in it. Reference: [JavaScript Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Looping over rows to retrieve cell values is effective, but can get ugly and hard to maintain. Consider that all the responses to a question would appear in the same row if we transposed the 2-d Array... recall high-school matrix mathematics. The `transpose` function from [Google Spreadsheet Script - How to Transpose / Rotate Multi-dimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621470/google-spreadsheet-script-how-to-transpose-rotate-multi-dimensional-array/16705104#16705104) will help us out here.

#### Code

```
//a function to update Question 2's answer options
function updateChoices() {
  //open the existing survey form  
  var form = FormApp.openById('1oaL64gVahL1wpIBeLJeRKclOHnso8Ai8sOVW9akxNhs');

  //retrieve existing Question 2
  var items = form.getItems();
  //var type = items[1].getType() == FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX;  // If you want to check, uncomment this
  var question2 = items[1].asCheckboxItem();  // Specify item type

  //retrieve previously submitted responses from response spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");

  // Get all the answers to question 2, so far...
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);  // All responses, headers sliced off
  var answersSoFar = transpose(values)[2];  // Question 2 responses

  //update the choices for the question
  question2.setChoiceValues(answersSoFar);
}

// See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16705104/1677912
function transpose(a)
{
  return Object.keys(a[0]).map(function (c) { return a.map(function (r) { return r[c]; }); });
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to see my vote up then stop reading now (and eventually turn off your computer)... excellent :-)  +1