# Loop not working for column match

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a loop that work to match row value from bottom and it goes like this:-

```
var lastRow = s3.getLastRow();
var dataRange = s3.getRange(1, 1,lastRow).getValues();
for(var k=0;k<dataRange.length;k++)
{doing something}
```

However, I am getting no result when I am trying to do the same thing with column match, here is my loop for column match that does not do anything.

```
var lastColumn = s3.getLastColumn();
var match2 = s3.getRange(1, 1,lastColumn).getValues();
for (var b = 0; b < match2.length; b++) 
{if (range[j][0] == match2[0][b])
{ do something } 
}
```

Please suggest what I am missing.

This is taken right out of the documentation:

```
getRange(row, column, numRows)  Range   Returns the range with the top left cell at the given coordinates, and with the given number of rows.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

match2.length is the number of rows in the array or the range.

This array  `[[x,x,x],[y,y,y],[z,z,z]...]` has three x's in the first row, 3 y's in the second row and so on.  So in `s3.getRange(1, 1,lastColumn).getValues();` lastColumn is the number of rows in that range.  Essentially it's easier to read each row and then get the column one at a time.  Or you could transpose your data like a matrix and then read the columns that are now rows.

A loop looking for "Big Macs':

```
function myFunction() 
{
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
    var rg=ss.getRange("A1:Z1");
    var vA=rg.getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<vA[0].length;j++)
      {
        if(vA[i][j]=="Big Mac")
        {
          SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Do not eat this burger as it has massive amounts of fat in it.');
          break;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

In these two dimensional arrays obtained by commands such as var data = range.getValues(); data.length = the number of rows and data[0].length = the  number of columns. So total number of array elements data.length x data[0].length some of which may be null.  Many programmers new to Google Apps Scripting have problems in this area.  In fact I had a lot of trouble with it so I ended up doing some extra work to help bolster my understanding and you can read about it [here](https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/javascript-array-difficulties).

These arrays look like the following: [[0,1,2,3,4,5...],[0,1,2,3,4,5...],[0,1,2,3,4,5...]...].  So vA is an array of arrays and so the term vA.length is equal to the number of elements in vA and simply put it's also equal to the number rows.

Comment: Basically I am trying to match data through "A1:Z1" what should my for loop be like?

Comment: @Mask There's a simple loop.

Comment: [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ec0m2wEGeZq6qBsitRLMAsrtJrj_GaGSQdR1IleIZVs/edit?usp=sharing) is the link to the spreadsheet can you tell me what is wrong. the column loop is in line 27.

Comment: Just because you decided to put the number of columns into the range function where the number rows belongs does not change how the function works.

Comment: If you want to search through the columns then you might consider transposing the data.  Take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16705104/7215091).  Transpose the data and columns become rows.

Comment: Length - gives you a total number of elements!!!
To get number of rows use extension method .GetLength(0)
To get number of columns - .GetLength(1)

Comment: @GlebB I believe in this case length also is the number of rows.  I don't believe there is a GetLength method in either arrays or ranges. I've looked [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and there is length property in array but I can't find any GetLength() method in either ranges or arrays.  Perhaps you could shed some light on the issue by providing a reference that we could read.  Thank You

Comment: Yes. I didn't mention that you use not smth like C# - there you have such Array methods. In your case it should work.

  Usually when you work with 2-dimensional array we use [ , ]  not [ ] [ ] - it is for jagged arrays.

Comment: Well I don't see any c# tags here so I think it's better to keep the thread focused on the question at hand.