# Simple data collage spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to automate a spreadsheet using an app script.
Copy data from one tab to another. Column D6:D10 to ("sheet1") to A4:E4 ("sheet2"), I tried several codes and I have failed.
Can someone help me? Apparently it's simple, but I can't.

Comment: try: `=TRANSPOSE(sheet1!D6:D10)`

Comment: Thank you friend. But I wanted via app script because I'm using a button.

Comment: Look here for a cool transpose: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16705104/7215091