# How do I delete a column that contains a substring or is empty?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Below is my code:

`delCol` tracks how many columns have been deleted (to keep the iterations aligned)

`sheet` is the active spreadsheet

`data` is the array of values from the row I'm searching through, retrieved via `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("2:2").getValues();`

```
function deleteRows() {
  var delCol = 0;
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("2:2").getValues();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  for(var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
    if(data[0][i-delCol].indexOf("txt-to-delete") > -1 || data[0][i-delCol] == ""){
      sheet.deleteColumn(i - delCol + 1);
      delCol++;
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this code, each and EVERY column is deleted.

Comment: Please share the spreadsheet

Comment: You will delete some column that you do not intend, because you delete from beginning column to last column, please reverse it, for(var i = data[0].length-1; i > 0; i--)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) a 2D-Array of the data contained in the range is copied to your scripts runtime's memory. After that, if you modify the range's data (using calls such as [`setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)))  the data in your sheet will be modified, but not the data in your 2D-Array.

More specifically, the mistake in your code is when evaluating the *if* statement's condition. You are taking into account `delCol` when accessing your 2D-Array, when in fact, you needn't do it. See below a correction of your code:

```js
function deleteRows() {
  var delCol = 0;
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("2:2").getValues();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  for(var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
    if (data[0][i].indexOf("txt-to-delete") > -1 || data[0][i] == "") {
      sheet.deleteColumn(i - delCol + 1);
      delCol++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Toblor glad I was able to help! ;) please consider [upvoting/accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Cheers!

Comment: Wish I could upvote, but I don't have enough reputation yet! :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function runOne(s) {
  var s=s||'deleteme';//The substring
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=transpose(rg.getValues());
  var d=0;
  for(var i=0;i-d<vA.length;i++) {
    var deleted=false;
    if(vA[i-d].join('').length==0) {
      vA.splice(i-d++,1);
      deleted=true;
    }
    var rs=vA[i-d].join(' ');
    if(!deleted && rs.indexOf(s)!=-1) {
      vA.splice(i-d++,1);
    }
  } 
  sh.clearContents();
  var oA=transpose(vA);
  sh.getRange(1,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
}

function transpose(a) {
  return Object.keys(a[0]).map(function (c) { return a.map(function (r) { return r[c]; }); });
}
```

[Transpose Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16705104/7215091)