# How to import cell data in map list format from app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hashmap

[image]

If there is a cell configured like this, the desired result is

```
{samsung, [Galaxy S20, Galaxy S21, Galaxy S22, Galaxy S23]}, {apple, [iPhone 13]}, {lg,[g7, g8]}
```

In this way, I would like to obtain data in Java's `HashMap<String, List<String>>` format.

What should I do?

Comment: No direct way. Loop through to create `Map`

Comment: @TheMaster If so, does spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getValues() read horizontally in the specified range, do you know how to read horizontally?

Comment: Sheets api can read horizontally. But it's easy to transpose: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16705104

Comment: @TheMaster Sorry... Oh, not horizontally, but vertically.. 

I read Samsung row, and then apple row.. This way

Comment: I got what you mean. The previous comment is correct and perfect. Sheets api can read both ways( use Advanced Google services). But the easy way is just to transpose. See previous link.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you so much. Thanks to you, I solved it!

Comment: Try adding a answer, if you think it'll be of help to the community.

Comment: @TheMaster How to filter out empty cell values?

Comment: [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: @TheMaster I just filtered it with trim().length.

But const transposedArr = d[0].map((_, i) => d.map((r) => r[i]));

This phrase cannot be filtered. Can you give an example?

sorry for being annoying.

Comment: I'm not sure about the expected output or the cells you want to filter. But it is possible with filter. Kindly ask a new question providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**. Avoid sharing [images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), which are hard to copy.

Comment: @TheMaster I clearly rewrote what I wanted to do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77238296/how-to-specify-the-maximum-area-when-using-getnextdatarange-in-google-script

Answer (score 0):

Try [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/ 
//getValues result
const d = [
  ['Samsung', 'Apple'],
  ['Galaxy S20', 'iPhone 13'],
  ['Galaxy S21', 'iPhone14'],
];

//Transpose example if needed 
const transposedArr = d[0].map((_, i) => d.map((r) => r[i]));
console.log(transposedArr);

const m = d.reduce((a, r) => {
  const o = Array.isArray(a) ? a.reduce((o, c) => ((o[c] = []), o), {}) : a;
  r.forEach((e, i) => o[d[0][i]].push(e));
  return o;
});
console.log(m);
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```