# How to specify the maximum area when using getNextDataRange() in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

|  | C | D | E | F | g |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Income | invest | Pension | emergency fund | food expenses |
| 6 | salary | stock | retirement pension | travel account | food ingredients |
| 7 | bonus | gold |  | reserve account | eat out |
| 8 |  | virtual currency |  |  | cafe |
| 9 |  | Savings |  |  |  |
| 10 |  | Deposit |  |  |  |

Let’s assume you have Excel like this.

1. Area designation problem.
   Write the following script based on column C5:

```
spreadsheet.getRange('C5').activate();
spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).activate();
spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
console.log(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getValues())
```

This will select the rows from C to G,
The selected columns are columns 5 through 7.

In this case I want up to C5:G10 to be selected.

I want to know this method.
(The range should not be specified arbitrarily.)

2. How to process the value of a designated cell

If number 1 is solved, the data format I want to obtain is as follows.
for example

Like Map<String, List>
[Income={salary, bonus},invest={stock, gold,virtual currency, Savings, Deposit}...]

The reason I want to get it like this is that column 5 is like the title of each item,
Starting from column 6 are the elements of each title. (I think you will understand if you look at the table.)

After obtaining the data like this, I would like to implement the following actions.

[image]

Comment: Good on using tables. But, Avoid asking two or more questions per post. A question should be focused, so that other users  searching for a question may find a specific answer. About 1. Tried `sheet.getDataRange()`?

Comment: If you going write code in apps script I would recommend minimizing the use of merged cells.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Are you asking for the table shown at the top of your question, transposed to look like the table at the bottom with merged cells?  And is there data beyond row 10?

Comment: @TheMaster Even if I do sheet.getDataRange(), I don't get the area I want.

Comment: Is there anything below D10?

Comment: @The Master No exist

Comment: Try ```sheet.getRange(`C5:G${sheet.getLastRow()}`)```

Comment: To be clear `Like Map<String, List>`  cannot be easily converted to your picture. Also, as @Cooper said Merging cells is a strict no no... even if you're not using apps script.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would constuct the table shown at the bottom.  I'don't know what all the `activate`s are for but probably not needed.

**Code.gs**

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let values = sheet.getRange(5,1,sheet.getLastRow()-4,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    // transpose the array;
    let transpose = [];
    for( let i=0; i<values[0].length; i++ ) {
      transpose.push([]);
      for( let j=0; j<values.length; j++ ) {
        if( values[j][i] !== "" ) transpose[i][j] = values[j][i];
      }
    }
    // now get the skyline
    let skyline = transpose.map( row => row.length-1 );
    // now form final array
    let results = [];
    transpose.forEach( row => {
        let j = 0;
        row.forEach( (item,i) => {
            if( i === 0 ) {
              j = results.push([item])-1;
            }
            else if( i === 1 ) {
              results[j].push(item)
            }
            else {
              results.push(["",item]);
            }
          }
        );
      }
    );
    sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    sheet.getRange(1,1,results.length,2).setValues(results);
    // now merge cells
    let i = 1;
    skyline.forEach( j => {
        let range = sheet.getRange(i,1,j,1)
        range.merge();
        range.setVerticalAlignment("middle");
        i = i+j;
      }
    );
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [Sheet.getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))
- [Array.map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)
- [Arrow function =>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [Array.push()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)
- [Range.merge()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#merge())
- [Range.setVerticalAlignment()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setverticalalignmentalignment)

Comment: By following this method, the problem was almost solved. I would like to ask additional questions. As an example in the picture above, there is a major category called Income and a subcategory called salary and bonus.

Currently, Income is merged into cells i19 and i20, salary is set to be placed in cell j19, and bonus is placed in cell j20.

Is there a way to setValues the salary in cell K19 and the bonus in cell K20?

That is, not right next to it, but in the next cell.

Comment: That's not waht your screen shot shows.

Comment: So this is an additional question.

Is what I asked in the comment earlier possible? If possible how?

Comment: Of course its possible but only you seem to know the logic about which column has only 1 major category and which has more than one.  I've shown you how to tanspose the matrix so that row 1 becomes column 1. Each column entry after that may be a minor or not.

Comment: It has nothing to do with transpose, right?
Written as an example
sheet.getRange(1,1,results.length,2).setValues(results);
I think this has something to do with it?