# How do I get each cell address using getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT)?

Tags: google-apps-script

|  | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test1 | test6 | test11 | test16 |
| 2 | test2 | test7 | test12 | test17 |
| 3 | test3 | test8 | test13 | test18 |
| 4 | test4 | test9 | test14 | test19 |
| 5 | test5 | test10 | test15 | test20 |

In this case, select cells based on each zero distance using getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT) based on D1.

However, the cell address obtained here is in D1:G1 format.

Rather than this, I want to get D1, E1, F1, G1 like this.

If you get it in list format, then
I want to repeat each list and get each data by doing getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN) based on each cell.

It's like Java's List<String, Map> format.

Comment: It is quite easy. Get the range then get the row and column of the upper left cell. Then get the values. Then loop through the values with indexes for the row and column add those indexes to the row and column of the upper left-hand corner. Use them to get the range of the cell and get the A1 notation. It’s very easy.

Comment: I use this technique to break apart ranges in a rangelist

Comment: Perhaps if you explained why you want each cell reference we can point you to a better solution.  If I know the range D1:G1 then I know the first and last column and every one inbetween.

Comment: @Cooper Can you give an example?

Comment: I'd prefer to see you try it first and if you have any problems return with what you have done

Comment: @TheWizEd As I gave as an example, if you know D1, E1, F1, and G1 in D1:G1,
I want to know Col information using getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN) based on D1.

So, the information you want is based on the table above.
With List<Map<String, List<String>>

{{test1,[test2,test3,test4,test5]}, {test6, [test7,test8,test9,test10]},...}

I want to get it this way.

Comment: But you didn't say why?

Comment: @TheWizEd Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77265684/i-want-to-obtain-data-only-from-the-area-i-need-using-app-script

Comment: How many of these do you have.  I answered this question on Oct 6 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77238296/how-to-specify-the-maximum-area-when-using-getnextdatarange-in-google-script/77245615#77245615

Comment: @TheWizEd The execution result is different from the table above. There is no merge function.