# I want to obtain data only from the area I need using App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

There is a table as below.

|  | C | D | E | F | g |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Income | invest | Pension | emergency fund | food expenses |
| 6 | salary | stock | retirement pension | travel account | food ingredients |
| 7 | bonus | gold |  | reserve account | eat out |
| 8 |  | virtual currency |  |  | cafe |
| 9 |  | Savings |  |  |  |
| 10 |  | Deposit |  |  |  |

where

```
itemManagementSheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).activate();
itemManagementSheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
```

If you use , the specified range is C5:g7.

However, I want the range to be designated as C7 for column C, D10 for column D, E6 for column E, F7 for column F, and G8 for column G.

So I thought of various methods.

Method 1:

```
getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).activate();
```

Use to obtain only the horizontal range. The result is C5:G5
Here, the range of C5:G5 is obtained in the form of a list as C5,D5,E5,F5,G5, and the range is obtained based on each item through `getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.Down).activate();`

But I don't know how to convert C5:G5 to C5,D5,E5,F5,G5 here.

Method 2:
Set C5 as the starting point and use C5 as the standard.
`getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();` If you did it

Then move the cell to D5 and call `getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();` And... repeat this until G5.

But I don't know how to move the cells to D5 after processing C5.

Ultimately, what you want to do by specifying a scope is as follows:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77238296/edit Question 2 in the question.

I don't know how to get the data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify the maximum area when using getNextDataRange() in Google Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77238296/how-to-specify-the-maximum-area-when-using-getnextdatarange-in-google-script)

Answer (score 0):

GS:

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  const vs  = sh.getRange("C5:G10").getValues().flat().filter(e => e);
  const arr = ["Income","invest","Pension","emergencyfund","foodexpenses","salary","stock","retirementpension","travelaccount","foodingredients","bonus","gold","reserveaccount","eatout","virtualcurrency","cafe","Savings","Deposit"];
  const [[Income,   invest, Pension,    emergencyfund,foodexpenses],[salary,    stock,  retirementpension,  travelaccount,  foodingredients],[bonus,    gold,,reserveaccount,   eatout],[,virtualcurrency,,,cafe],[,Savings,,,],[,Deposit,,,]] = sh.getRange("C5:G10").getValues();
  [Income,invest,Pension,emergencyfund,foodexpenses,salary,stock,retirementpension,travelaccount,foodingredients,bonus,gold,reserveaccount,eatout,virtualcurrency,cafe,Savings,Deposit].forEach((v,i) => Logger.log(`${arr[i]}:${v}`))
}
```

Sheet2

|  | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| 7 | 11 | 12 |  | 13 | 14 |
| 8 |  | 15 |  |  | 16 |
| 9 |  | 17 |  |  |  |
| 10 |  | 18 |  |  |  |

Your table:

|  | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Income | invest | Pension | emergency fund | food expenses |
| 6 | salary | stock | retirement pension | travel account | food ingredients |
| 7 | bonus | gold |  | reserve account | eat out |
| 8 |  | virtual currency |  |  | cafe |
| 9 |  | Savings |  |  |  |
| 10 |  | Deposit |  |  |  |

```
Execution log
3:22:38 PM  Notice  Execution started
3:22:28 PM  Info    Income:1
3:22:28 PM  Info    invest:2
3:22:28 PM  Info    Pension:3
3:22:28 PM  Info    emergencyfund:4
3:22:28 PM  Info    foodexpenses:5
3:22:28 PM  Info    salary:6
3:22:28 PM  Info    stock:7
3:22:28 PM  Info    retirementpension:8
3:22:28 PM  Info    travelaccount:9
3:22:28 PM  Info    foodingredients:10
3:22:28 PM  Info    bonus:11
3:22:28 PM  Info    gold:12
3:22:28 PM  Info    reserveaccount:13
3:22:28 PM  Info    eatout:14
3:22:28 PM  Info    virtualcurrency:15
3:22:28 PM  Info    cafe:16
3:22:28 PM  Info    Savings:17
3:22:28 PM  Info    Deposit:18
3:22:40 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: [If you would like to have a tool for making these kinds of assignments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77290663/do-you-have-a-better-way-to-facilitate-the-creation-of-an-array-literal-assignme)