# Do you have a better way to facilitate the creation of an Array Literal Assignment

Tags: google-apps-script

It is beneficial to be able to avoid the use of multiple getValue()s with one getValues() but in complex spreadsheets the assignment can be very difficult to create.  So I've been thinking about it and I have implemented one which utilizes the `<textarea>` tag but it still feels a bit clunky. So I was wondering if anyone has a better idea.  Even if you don't wish to take the time to implement it please let me know perhaps I will.

The current version utilizes a textarea.

The idea is simple if in my current code the testcode function is utilizing the dataRange of Sheet2 and you have several single values that you wish to extract from that data set but your not quite sure how to use an array literal to achieve this so your probably thinking maybe I should get get them with a few getValue() calls but you know that will be more time consuming.

So these functions allow me to go select the area of the data starting with the appropriate line depending upon your code.  And make the assignment with the help of the generated A1 Notation and when I press createAssignment button it strips away everything but the variables and the remain commas.I just copy it and paste it into my assignment and run the code to test it.

It works pretty well but there's still a lot of detailed editing I'd like to avoid but I haven't quite figured how how to overcome it.

Sorry I know this isn't the kind of question you were hoping for and I'm not interesting in wasting your time.  So I apologize for risking this type of question. But even now I find it a lost easier to make those type of assignments.

The GS:

```
function launchArrayLitAssDialog() {
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ah2').evaluate().setWidth("600").setHeight(300), "ArrayLiteralAssignment Dialog")
}

function getMyJSON() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg = sh.getActiveRange();
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  const orow = rg.getRow();
  const ocol = rg.getColumn();
  const ovs = vs.map((r, i) => {
    return r.map((c, j) => sh.getRange(i + orow, j + ocol).getA1Notation() + '-')
  })
  return JSON.stringify(ovs).replace(/],/g, '],\n');
}
   
function testcode() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  const rg = sh.getRange(14,1,sh.getLastRow()-13,sh.getLastColumn());
  const [cols,hs,...vs] = rg.getValues();
  const [[A,,,,],[,,,,],[,,,,],[,,,,],[,,B,,],[,,,,],[,,,,],[,,,,],[,,,,],[C,,,,]]=vs;
  Logger.log('A: %s B: %s C: %s',A,B,C)
}
```

The html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <title>Array Literal Assignment Dialog</title>
  <body>
    <div>
      <textarea cols="40" rows="15" id="myJSON"><?= getMyJSON() ?></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="paste">
      <textarea cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <br><input type="button" id="btn1" value="CreateAssignment" onClick="createAssignment();" />

    <script>
      function createAssignment() {
        var js = document.getElementById("myJSON").value;
        var vs = JSON.parse(js);
        var ovs = vs.map(r => {
          return r.map(c => {
            if(c.slice(c.indexOf("-")+1).length > 0) {
              return c.slice(c.indexOf("-")+1);
            } else {
              return '';
            }
          })
        });
        document.getElementById("myJSON").value = JSON.stringify(ovs).replace(/"/g,'');
        document.getElementById("btn1").disabled = true;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Demo:

[image]

Sorry for the lousy video but it's hard to fit everything in and remain under 2MB.

Here's a version of launchArrayLitAssDialog that embeds the html into the function so that you don't require a separate html file any longer.

```
function launchArrayLitAssDialog() {
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  let html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><base target="_top"><title>Array Literal Assignment Dialog</title><body><div><textarea cols="40" rows="15" id="myJSON"><?= getMyJSON() ?></textarea></div><div id="paste"><textarea cols="40" rows="3"></textarea></div><br><input type="button" id="btn1" value="CreateAssignment" onClick="createAssignment();" /><script>function createAssignment() {var js = document.getElementById("myJSON").value;var vs = JSON.parse(js);var ovs = vs.map(r => {return r.map(c => {if(c.slice(c.indexOf("-")+1).length > 0) {return c.slice(c.indexOf("-")+1);} else {return "";}})});document.getElementById("myJSON").value = JSON.stringify(ovs).replace(/"/g,"");document.getElementById("btn1").disabled = true;}</script></body></html>';
  ui.showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createTemplate(html).evaluate().setWidth("600").setHeight(300), "ArrayLiteralAssignment Dialog")
}
```

If you come up with a better ui I'm still hoping for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

**An easy way to get all of your spreadsheet form data all at one time rather than making multiple getValue() calls**

I've played around with the ui a bit and I really like this one and it's quite simple and flexible. I've embedded the html into the code and I load it with templated html.  You simply select the cells you wish the values of then launch the script.  It figures out the minimum rectangle and makes the assignment with A1Notation as the variable and then it populates another textarea with an  array where column one is the a1notation of the selections and you can add the variable names all at one time push replace and then copy it puts it into the clip board and you paste it into you code.

gs:

```
function newArrayLiteralAssignment() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rgl = breakUpRangeList(ss, sh, sh.getActiveRangeList());
  const ob = rgl.getRanges().reduce((a, r, i) => {
    let a1 = r.getA1Notation().toLowerCase();
    let row = r.getRow();
    let col = r.getColumn();
    if (i == 0) {
      a.rowStart = row;
      a.rowEnd = row;
      a.columnStart = col;
      a.columnEnd = col;
    } else {
      a.rowStart = (a.rowStart < row) ? a.rowStart : row;
      a.rowEnd = (a.rowEnd > row) ? a.rowEnd : row;
      a.columnStart = (a.columnStart < col) ? a.columnStart : col;
      a.columnEnd = (a.columnEnd > col) ? a.columnEnd : col;
    }
    a.count++;
    a.ranges.push(a1);
    return a;
  }, { rowStart: 0, columnStart: 0, rowEnd: 0, columnEnd: 0, count: 0, ranges: [], getA1: function () { return sh.getRange(this.rowStart, this.columnStart, this.rowEnd - this.rowStart + 1, this.columnEnd - this.columnStart + 1).getA1Notation() } });
  let o = sh.getRange(ob.getA1()).getValues().map((r, i) => {
    return r.map((c, j) => {
      let idx = ob.ranges.indexOf(sh.getRange(i + ob.rowStart, j + ob.columnStart).getA1Notation().toLowerCase());
      return (~idx) ? ob.ranges[idx] : "";
    });
  });
  //let html = `<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <base target="_top"> <title>Array Literal Assignment Dialog</title> <body> <div> <textarea cols="60" rows="3" id="myJSON"><?= myassignment ?></textarea><br></div> <input type="button" id="btn3" value="Copy" onClick="doCopy();"> <script> function doCopy() { var textbox=document.getElementById('myJSON'); textbox.select(); document.execCommand('copy'); google.script.run .withSuccessHandler(function(){ google.script.host.close(); }) .justADelay(); } </script> </body> </html>`;
  let html = `<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <base target="_top"> <title>Array Literal Assignment Dialog</title> <style>input{padding:2px 5px 2px 0px;}</style> </head> <body> <input type="button" id="btn4" value="Replace" onClick="doReplace();"> <input type="button" id="btn3" value="Copy" onClick="doCopy();"> <div> <textarea cols="60" rows="3" id="assign"> <?= myassignment ?> </textarea> <br> <textarea cols="60" rows="2" id="variables"> <?= variables ?> </textarea> </div> <script> function doCopy() { var textbox=document.getElementById('assign'); textbox.select(); document.execCommand('copy'); google.script.run .withSuccessHandler(function(){ google.script.host.close(); }).justADelay(); } function doReplace() { var obj = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("variables").value).reduce((acc,[a,b]) => { acc[a] = b; acc.pA.push(a); return acc; },{pA:[]}); var s = document.getElementById("assign").value; obj.pA.forEach(p => { s = s.replace(p,obj[p]); }); document.getElementById("assign").value = s; } console.log("End of Code"); </script> </body> </html>`;
  let t = HtmlService.createTemplate(html);
  t.myassignment = `const ${JSON.stringify(o).replace(/"/g, '')} = sheet.getRange("${ob.getA1()}").getValues();`;
  t.variables = JSON.stringify(ob.ranges.map(e => [e,'']));
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(t.evaluate().setWidth(800).setHeight(350), "Array Literal Assignment Dialog")
}
```

The html for the dialog is embedded into the code so it's pretty easy to use.

Demo:

[image]