# Create function to set "I10" value as: Current value + Current value of cell "I12" + Current value of cell "J12"

Tags: function, google-apps-script

I need help identifying the current values of "I12" and "J12" in the below function in order to ADD them to the current value of "I10" and set the product as the new value of "I10"

I have tried multiple times different ways but it throws up errors. Below is my current function with **"I12"+"J12"** highlighted in bold and asterix as what I need help to find.

---

```
function PRODUCE(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 sheet = ss.getSheetByName("PLAYER 1");
 const range = sheet.getRange("I10");

 range.setValue(range.getValue()+(**"I12"+"J12"**)); 

}
```

---

Thank you!

I have tried:

1.

```
function PRODUCE(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet = ss.getSheetByName("PLAYER 1");
  const range = sheet.getRange("I10");

  range.setValue(range.getValue()+("I12"+"J12")); 

}
```

result was 0I12J12

2.

```
function PRODUCE(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet = ss.getSheetByName("PLAYER 1");
  const range = sheet.getRange("I10");

  range.setValue(range.getValue()+sum(I12:J12)); 

}
```

result was error missing argument

please help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```
function PRODUCE(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet = ss.getSheetByName("PLAYER 1");
  var valueI12 = sheet.getRange("I12").getValue()
  var valueJ12 = sheet.getRange("J12").getValue()
  var valueI10 = sheet.getRange("I10").getValue()
  var newTotal = valueI10+valueI12+valueJ12
  sheet.getRange("I10").setValue(newTotal)
}
```

---

The script can be considerably simplified by consolidating the variables, but this answer is designed to help the OP understand where each value comes from, and how the Total is calculated, and how the Total is updated.

Answer (score 1):

A little different way to make assignments:

```
function PRODUCE() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const [[vI10,], [,], [vI12, vJ12]] = sh.getRange("I10:J12").getValues();
  let sum = [vI10, vI12, vJ12].reduce((a, e) => (a += e, a), 0);
  sh.getRange("I10").setValue(sum);
}
```

You can use the tool found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77294094/7215091) to assist you in making this type of assignment in more complex situations

Comment: Very elegant. Much nicer use of JavaScript than the other answer.

Comment: Yeh but you are correct that the other is easier to understand

Comment: Thank you, I have implemented the first answer and it works, thank you for yours too I will keep a note for future reference and understanding.

Comment: @TheoMillington If you have implemented the first example how about selecting it as your answer.

Comment: thank you, i've never done this before now i know