# Google Sheets - Checkbox to copy data from one workbook to another

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am trying to set up a checkbox that would work like a button that is going to take the value of certain cells in a sheet on a Workbook, and copy those values on a different Workbook, starting from the first empty row, and moving downwards from there every time the "button" is pressed.

So, the way my sheet works is as follows:

Cell C4 has a Data Validation list of people's names. Cells E6 and G6 display different values depending on the name selected on C4.

The script should take C4, E6 and G6 values, and copy them in the second workbook sheet on A1, B1, and C1 respectively. When the next name is selected, editing the checkbox will copy the corresponding values in the second workbook sheet on A2, B2, and C2, and so on.

The idea is that every time the checkbox is checked, it unchecks itself after running the script, but I know how to do that part.

I have another workbook doing something similar with an "actual" button using an image, and I know how to do this with a checkbox within the same workbook, but I can't figure out how to combine this two to achieve what I want, which is why I am not providing an example. If someone could help with it, it would be great!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I have another workbook doing something similar with an "actual" button using an image, and I know how to do this with a checkbox within the same workbook, but I can't figure out how to combine this two to achieve what I want`. Can I ask you about the details of it? Do you want to merge 2 existing functions?

Comment: No, what I mean is that I know how to solve those two different, but similar problems, but I don't know how to apply that knowledge to my current problem. That is why I need ask for help.

Comment: Take a lock at getValues() and setValues().  Or perrhaps sheet.copyTo(() which copie an entire sheet and then you can use copyTo() from range to range.

Answer (score 0):

Moves 3 values from one Spreadsheet to another spreadsheet

```
function myfunk02() {
  const ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();//source
  const sh = ss1.getSheetByName("Sheet0");//source
  const [[a, , , ,], [, , , ,], [, , b, , c]] = sh.getRange("C4:G6").getValues();//values
  const ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.test1id);//destination
  const dsh = ss2.getSheetByName("Sheet0");//destination
  dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 3).setValues([[a, b, c]]);//placed on the next available line in columns 1,2,3
}
```

- [ArrayLiteralAssignment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77294094/7215091)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)