Transposing each row of the source file sheet to each destination file sheet
I'm trying to transpose each row, like row3 B3:H3 of the Source file to a column: B3-B9 of the destination file1 sheet. Here's the sample file for public: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ptQpnUhW_Bvs637pTfPTV7VMsBaDP-XudEasjo2vCaY/edit?gid=0#gid=0
Already tried the =Arrayformula(Transpose(IMPORTRANGE("xxxxxxxxxx", "Sheet!B3:H3"))) and the Transpose formula: =transpose(Sheet1!B3:H3). Both are working. However, I want to automate it.

Consider providing input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Click here to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I want to transpose row3: b3-h3 of the Source File to column b3-b9 of the Destination File 1, which is located in Source File Column/cell A3 via URL. And transpose row4: b4-h4 of the Source File to column b3-b9 of the Destination File 2, which is located in Source File Column/cell A3 via URL. And do it again for the rest of the rows.

Transposing values to different sheets using Apps script
If you are trying to transfer values from one spreadsheet to different spreadsheets then transpose it, I am afraid it would be difficult to use Google Sheets to automate this process.
Considering that my understanding is correct, what you want to do is to transfer and transpose the row data of the source sheet to each destination spreadsheet that is located on the column A.
To achieve this, you can paste this code on your Google Apps script connected to your Google Sheets source file that you have shared through post.
Complete code:
function updateSheets() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet');
  const data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
  const richTextValues = sheet.getDataRange().getRichTextValues(); 

  data.slice(2).map((row, index) => {
    const titleCell = richTextValues[index + 2][0]; 
    const url = titleCell.getLinkUrl() || row[0]; 

    if (url && url.includes('/d/') && url.includes('gid=')) {
      const fileId = url.split('/d/')[1].split('/')[0];
      const sheetId = url.split('gid=')[1].split('#')[0];

      const targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId).getSheets().find(s => s.getSheetId() == sheetId);

      const rowData = row.slice(1); 
      const transposedData = rowData.map(value => [value]); 

      if (targetSheet) {
        targetSheet.getRange(2, 2, transposedData.length, 1).setValues(transposedData); 
      }

    } else {
      Logger.log("No valid URL found for row " + (index + 2));
    }
  });
}

Sample output:

References:

Map()
getDisplayValues()
setValues()


Please do not hesitate to try it on your end and let me know if you have any questions or clarification that needs modification on the posted answer.

There's no error, but it didn't transpose yet. The Destination file Sheet 1 didn't get the data from the Source file Sheet. Is this impossible with the Google spreadsheet or is it best just to create a formula in the cell of the Destination file Sheet 1?

There are numbers of reasons why the data aren't being transferred. 1. Do you have editor access to the spreadsheet? 2. Are the destination spreadsheets/sheet/cells protected?, etc. In such cases, you must have the required permissions to transfer the data. +Using Google sheets formulas is quite difficult to implement since you want the data being transferred to different 'Spreadsheets' all at once (automate) - If my understanding is correct.

You want to take a range in spreadsheet file#1 and transpose it to spreadsheet file#2.
Consider this script which copies the static data to spreadsheet file#2.
Aspects to note

The data array is transposed in a very simple routine created by @Mogsdad
Hyperlinks lose their url when getValues and setValues are applied.

So the script re-copies the hyperlinks using .getRichTextValues and setRichTextValues


Time values in column "G" and "H" are displayed as dates when getValues and setValues are applied.

So the script applies .setNumberFormat("h:mm am/pm") to format them as per the source.




function update2File2() {

  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<<insert spreadsheet id>>")
  var sourceSheet = source.getSheetByName("Sheet")
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("<<insert Target sheet name>>")

  // get the source data rows
  var sourceB = sourceSheet.getRange('B3').getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS).getValues();
  var numRowsOfData = +sourceB.length-2

  // get all the source data (including hyperlinks)
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange(3,2,numRowsOfData,7).getValues()
  
  // transpose the array
  var transposedSourceData = transpose(sourceData)
 
  // copy the transposed array to the target sheet
  targetSheet.getRange(3,2,7,numRowsOfData).setValues(transposedSourceData)

  // update the hyperlinks
  // get the hyperlinks as Richtext Values from Source sheet
  var hyperlinkData = sourceSheet.getRange(3,6,numRowsOfData,1).getRichTextValues()
  // transpose the array (it is only 1 row)
  var transposedHyperlinks = transpose(hyperlinkData)
  // update the hyperlinks on the target sheet as Rich text values
  targetSheet.getRange(7,2,1,numRowsOfData).setRichTextValues(transposedHyperlinks)

  // format the time values as h:mmAM/PM
  // rows 8 and 9
  targetSheet.getRange(8,2,2,numRowsOfData).setNumberFormat("h:mm am/pm")
}

/*
//  Credit Mogsdad
//  How to Transpose / Rotate Multi-dimensional Array?
//  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16705104/1330560
*/
function transpose(a)
{
  return Object.keys(a[0]).map(function (c) { return a.map(function (r) { return r[c]; }); });
}


Output


You want to take a range in spreadsheet file#1  and transpose it to spreadsheet file#2.
Try this formula:
=transpose(
  LET(
   imported,
   IMPORTRANGE("<<insert url of spreadsheet file#1>>","Sheet!B3:H"),
   filter(
    imported,
    IMPORTRANGE("<<insert url of spreadsheet file#1>>","Sheet!B3:B")<>""
   )
  )
 )


The formula uses the FILTER function because Column F of the original data is a hyperlink.
AQUERY function would return the same result BUT the hyperlink would be lost and only the hyperlink text would be returned.


Output

Adapted from the suggested answer by Prashanth K V in Google Docs Editors Help: Using filter function with importrange
