# How well does scriptDB work as substitute for storing data directly in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-analytics, google-apps-script

I want to retrieve data from Google Analytics API, create custom calculations and then push the aggregations to a Google Spreadsheets in order to reuse in Google Visualisation API app. My concern is that I'll hit the Spreadsheet cell quota very quickly with the raw data needed for the calculation.

I know scriptDB quota is 100MB but before I invest time and resources in learning how it works I'd like to get an idea whether it's feasible for storing raw analytics data (provided it's not too granular and it's just designed to answer specific questions) and how much of it I could realistically store in scriptDB (relative to spreadsheets) before I hit the quota.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For bulk data access (e.g. reading a table for Visualization), a spreadsheet will have a speed advantage over ScriptDb.  [What is faster: ScriptDb or SpreadsheetApp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145918/what-is-faster-scriptdb-or-spreadsheetapp) If you wish to support more sophisticated queries though, to "answer specific questions" as you mention, then ScriptDb will give you an edge, as query times vary with the number of results but should be unaffected by the query criteria themselves.

With data in a spreadsheet, you will be able to obtain a DataTable for Visualization with a single [`Range.getDataTable()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDataTable%28%29) operation. With ScriptDb, you will need to write a script to build your DataTable.

Regarding size constraints, it's not possible to really compare the two without knowing the size of your individual data elements. You're already aware of the general constraints:

- Spreadsheet, 40K cells, but may hit (unspecified) size limit before that, depending on data element sizes.
- ScriptDb, 50MB, 100MB or 200MB depending on account type. The number of objects that can be stored is affected by the complexity (depth) of the object and the size of the property names, and of course the size of data contained in the objects.

Ultimately, the question of which is best for your application is a matter of opinion, and of which factors matter most for the application. If the analytics data is tabular, then a spreadsheet offers advantages for implementation largely because of `Range.getDataTable()`, and is faster for bulk access. I'd recommend starting there, and considering a move to ScriptDb if and when you actually hit spreadsheet size or query performance limitations.

Comment: I start getting issues with spreadsheets after 5mb, and it becomes read-only around 10mb. I ran into this problem this week when I was trying to condense data I had across multiple spreadsheets feeding an Apps Script Dashboard.