# GAS. Storing data for a specific domain

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on an add-on in GAS. I know that with Google's PropertiesService it is possible to store data for a particular user,document or script, but I would like to store data specific to a domain. Is this possible? And if it is, how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spreadsheets are quite good data containers, easily shareable across your domain, large and pretty fast if used the right way (see this ["hit" post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145918/what-is-faster-scriptdb-or-spreadsheetapp/15149959#15149959) to confirm).

You can store and retrieve data as array data and easily convert it to JavaScript Objects as well.